# Trying to call from a nested array in a SwiftUI view

Tags: arrays, json, swift, model, swiftui

So I have a model [UserModel] with nested arrays [CityModel] and within that [TownModel]. I'm pretty sure the model is setup right but I think I have the syntax wrong for trying to reference the nested arrays.

Here is my UserModel.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let cities: [CityModel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case cities
    }
}

struct CityModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let towns: [TownModel]
}

struct TownModel: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

The problem comes in my CityRow.swift, where I would just like to display the name of a city (so I can then call it in CityList and show all the cities under a user).

```
struct CityRow: View {
    var city: [UserModel.CityModel]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(city.name)
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}

struct CityRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CityRow(city: userData[0])
    }
}
```

But I get this error when trying write out my 'city' variable.

```
'CityModel' is not a member type of 'UserModel'
```

I'm sure my syntax of "var city: [UserModel.CityModel]" is incorrect, but not sure how to do it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CityRow needs a city in order to call its name. CityModel is not a Member of UserModel but cities is.
I don't know your app or what you're trying to achieve but e.g. in a list you want to present every city thats in the array. 
Your CityRow needs `var city: CityModel` as a constructor. It could look like this (again, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, some more info/code would be helpful!).

Here's your CityRow

```
struct CityRow: View {
    var city: CityModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(city.name)
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the ForEach Loop that you could use in a list or something

```
ForEach(user.cities) {city in
    CityRow(city: city)
}
```

If you could edit your question with some more code, like the view that presents all the CityRows, it would be helpful!

Comment: Thanks for this, I started editing the post to kinda fill in the full extent of the help I needed and realized it was probably more appropriate as a separate post — which I have made here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635853/creating-a-series-of-master-detail-lists-from-a-single-json-file-in-swiftui

Comment: @FuegoDeBassi i answered there, even though there's another answer. The other answer could work but i did some adjustments. Have a nice day!