# Creating a series of master detail lists from a single JSON file in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, json, swiftui, master-detail

I'm trying to work through understanding how I can make data flow nicely through an app I'm building. I just want a basic master detail view where it starts with a list of all the top level objects(users), tapping one of them lets you see all the second level objects related to that top level (userX -> cities), and tapping one of them lets you see all the third level objects (userX -> cityX -> towns).

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "first_name": "Jimmy",
        "last_name": "Simms",
        "cities": [{
                "name": "New York City",
                "towns": [{
                        "name": "Brooklyn"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Manhatten"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Tokyo",
                "towns": [{
                        "name": "Churo"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Riponggi"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
...
]
```

I have a model that I think will work well for this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let cities: [CityModel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case cities
    }
}

struct CityModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let towns: [TownModel]
}

struct TownModel: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

However, what I'm struggling to do is to build this all into a series of list views that are connected to each other. I have the top level one, UserList.swift at least showing a list of the users.

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(userData) { user in
                NavigationLink(destination: UserRow(user: user)) {
                    UserRow(user: user)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"))
        }
    }
}

struct UserList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserList()
    }
}
```

And it's assistant view, UserRow:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserRow: View {
    var user: UserModel
    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(user.firstName)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text(user.lastName)
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct UserRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserRow(user: userData[0])
    }
}
```

UserList.swift Preview:

### [image: UserList.swift Preview]

What I can't figure out is how to write CityList/CityRow and TownList/TownRow such that I can drill down from the main screen and get a list related to the objected I tapped into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CityModel and TownModel need to conform to Identifiable, just add an id to them like you did in UserModel.

Than you need to edit your UserList NavigationLink:

```
NavigationLink(destination: CityList(cities: user.cities)) {
    Text(user.firstName)
}
```

The Navigation is now like this: UserList -> CityList -> TownList

CityList:

```
struct CityList: View {

    var cities: [CityModel]

    var body: some View {
        List (cities) { city in
            NavigationLink(destination: TownList(towns: city.towns)) {
                Text(city.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TownList:

```
struct TownList: View {

    var towns: [TownModel]

    var body: some View {
        List (towns) { town in
            Text(town.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps, in my test project it works!

Comment: @FuegoDeBassi thank you! If you need any help, let me know!

Comment: Ha, well if you have any ideas on this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652742/list-views-jittering-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

first you have to create CityListView and CityRow, like you did for users:

```
struct CityListView: View {
    var user: UserModel
    var body: some View {

            // don't forget to make CityModel Identifiable 
            List(user.cities) { city in
                CityRowView(city: city)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Cities"))
        }
    }
}

struct CityRowView: View {
    var city: CityModel
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(city. name)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

after that you need to change destination in NavigationLink (not **UserRow**, but new **CityListView**)

```
...
//NavigationLink(destination: UserRow(user: user)) {
NavigationLink(destination: CityListView(user: user)) {
    UserRow(user: user)
}
...
```

Another way is to declare variable "cities" as an array of CityModel and receive it from user:

```
struct CityListView: View {
    var cities: [UserModel]
    // list for array of cities
}

// in UserList
NavigationLink(destination: CityListView(cities: user.cities)) {
    UserRow(user: user)
}
```

P.S. Apple made excellent tutorial for navigations in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation